# How to give a text file into a shell function?

Tags: bash, function, shell, file

Hi I'm trying to make a function which should get a text file and then do some things on it and then echo. But when I try to execute it, it says `` syntax error near unexpected token `"$cat"' ``

```
#!/bin/usr/bash
  
cat=$(< cat_dialogue.txt)
 
function test_cat (){
    echo $1
}

test_cat($cat)
```

desired output:

```
>meow meow
```

Comment: That isn't how you call functions in bash. You call them the same way you'd call any command: `test_cat $cat`. See the bash manual for more details: [Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions)

Comment: Also, double-quote variable and parameter references to avoid weird parsing (i.e. `test_cat "$cat"` and `echo "$1"`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot this and many other common mistakes -- I recommend running all your scripts through it as a sanity-check. Oh, and I'm pretty sure you have "usr" and "bin" backward in your shebang line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example BASH function that strips a branchname:

```
#create function
function strip () {
#create local variable that takes input and fills $TEXT
    local TEXT=$1

    #stips the branch number from the branchname
    echo $TEXT | sed 's/-[0-9]*//2'
}

strip "testbranch-12345-28796"
```

hope it helps :) also check the BASH documentation as mentioned by @joshmeranda

Answer (score 1):

Your program may look like the following. Note all differences. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
cat=$(< cat_dialogue.txt)
 
test_cat() {
    echo "$1"
}

test_cat "$cat"
```